Master theorem recurrence solution
I have a function $T(n)$ that determines the time an algorithm needs to complete a task of size $n$:
$$T(n)=5T(n/4)+4T(n/2)+O(n),T(1)=1$$
When solving the recurrence, Wolfram provides the following closed form:
$$T(n)=-\frac{1}{9} (-1)^{-\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}} \left(4 n (-1)^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}}-9 c_1 (-5)^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}}-13+9 c_1\right)$$
However, as I am interested in finding a tight bound for the time complexity, I compared the closed form growth with $O(n^{\log _2(5)})$:
$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}-\frac{(-1)^{-\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}} \left(4 n (-1)^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}}-9 c_1 (-5)^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}}-13+9 c_1\right)}{9 n^{\log _2(5)}}=c_1$$
As seen, it results in the parameter $c_1$, proving they are asymptotically equal as $n\to\infty$ by the convergence to a real value. But, I am not sure about this result, as according to the master theorem, the bound must be $O(n^2)$. So, is it possible to solve the recurrence with a method that provides a simpler expression than the original result to verify if they are actually equivalent?

What version of Master Theorem are you using? AFAIK, the standard version (see this) does not apply (at least directly) in your case.
